# print a value if it is not zero

Tags: erlang

I need to print out a value if it is above zero:

```
info({mail, BoxPid, Messages, MessageCount, MessageDropCount}, Req, S) ->
    if MessageDropCount > 0 ->
            io:format("dropped=~p~n", [MessageDropCount]);
       true -> true
    end,
    ...,
    {loop, Req, S};
```

I do not like the `true -> true` part of the `if` expression. Is there a way to avoid it? Is there an idiom for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [If Then page at the ErlangCentral wiki](https://erlangcentral.org/wiki/index.php?title=If_Then) suggests these patterns:

- `[io:format("dropped=~p~n", [MessageDropCount]) || MessageDropCount > 0]`
- `MessageDropCount > 0 andalso io:format("dropped=~p~n", [MessageDropCount])`
- `MessageDropCount =< 0 orelse io:format("dropped=~p~n", [MessageDropCount])`

Answer (score 2):

You ca use a function with pattern matching:

```
info({mail, BoxPid, Messages, MessageCount, MessageDropCount}, Req, S) ->
    printIfNotZero(MessageDropCount,"dropped=~p~n"),
    ...,
    {loop, Req, S};

...
printIfNotZero(0,_) -> ok;
printIfNotZero(C,M) -> io:format(M, [C]).
```

EDIT: a more general function could be the following:

```
info({mail, BoxPid, Messages, MessageCount, MessageDropCount}, Req, S) ->
    printCond(MessageDropCount =/= 0,"dropped=~p~n",[MessageDropCount]),
    ...,
    {loop, Req, S};

...
printCond(false,_,_) -> ok;
printCond(true,Format,Arglist) -> io:format(Format,Arglist).
```

Comment: I'd even say that a more generic variant would be:

    `if(false, _) ->
        ok;
    if(true, Action) ->
        Action().`

Used like:

    `if(MessageDropCount > 0, fun() -> io:format("dropped=~p~n", [MessageDropCount]) end).`

Though, in fact, I've got the impression that both yours and mine solutions are too verbose/cumbersome for general usage and `MessageDropCount > 0 andalso io:format("dropped=~p~n", [MessageDropCount])` wins.

Comment: Yes, but I tried to give a straight answer to Akonsu question.I suspect that the problem is related to the log of some events that occur in the application; I have used multiple solutions for that from unconditional console print to the usage of a gen_event with a bunch of event handlers to log on console, in file or even in graphic interface. It is always a temptation to  give more information than it is asked but ... short is beautiful